# find folder from dynamic path

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory

I have JavaScript code that use

`node-find-folder`

find folder path from current location, but I need to find the folder on a shared network folder. Something like `\\10.158.47.25\c$\reports\{from here to look for folder}`.

How can I set the search to start from specific folder?

UPDATE:

this is the code I have

```
var ff, ff_result;

ff = require('node-find-folder');
ff_result = new ff('somefoldername');

console.log('image path : ' + ff_result);
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: @mplungjan I did research and didn't find any way to solve my issue! there is no easy way to say it but I don't have more details

Comment: Post your question here https://trello.com/b/Hc2tSxlR/node-find-folder

Comment: @mplungjan thanks will do